# Firebase crash reporting - Error in upload-sym (swift-demangle-command)

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, firebase-crash-reporting

Hi we have a project that uses firebase crash reporting. The project seem to work fine with other workstations but in my case I'm having an error regarding swift-demangle-command.

[image: swift-demangle-command]

I tried to look for other solutions in stackoverflow, but the problem is very rare so I can't find the solution. Please see the attached photo. Is it a hardware incompatibility?

EDIT:

Here's the code:

```
${SWIFT_DEMANGLE_COMMAND} <"${SCRATCH}" >|"${!SYMBOL_FILE}" || exit 1

if ((VERBOSE >= 2)); then
    xcnote "${EXECUTABLE##*/} (architecture ${ARCH}) symbol dump follows (first 20 lines):"
    head >&2 -n20 "${!SYMBOL_FILE}"
elif ((VERBOSE >= 1)); then
    xcnote "${EXECUTABLE##*/} (architecture ${ARCH}) symbol dump follows (first line only):"
    head >&2 -n1 "${!SYMBOL_FILE}"
fi

fcr_upload_files "${!SYMBOL_FILE}" || exit 1
```

Comment: For searchability: Please convert the image to text.

Comment: Hi there! I have added the code in the question.